# Awk command taking too much time for multiple files to execute while performing SHA2

Tags: linux, awk, sha256

I am trying to run awk sha2 command on multiple files at same time, but its taking so much time. File contains 5lacs rows and i am converting first column to SHA2. Here is my code

```
output="-SHA2.txt"
FILES="${filePath}/*"
for f in $FILES
  do
        echo $f
        awk -F '\\[\\^' 'BEGIN {OFS = "[^"}
        NR==1; NR>1{
        tmp="echo -n "$1" | sha256sum | cut -f1 -d\" \""
        tmp | getline cksum
        $1=cksum;
        print $0;
        close(tmp)
        }' $f > $f$output &
  done
```

This code was taking too much time more than 2 hrs to print 174 files. Each one has 500 000 lines.

Comment: You might want to give a generally understood number, "5 lacs" doesn't mean too much for most people outside India ;-)  --  I seem to remember that this is 500k...

Comment: Are you trying to run `sha256sum` on the name of each file or the complete contents of each file all at once or each individual line within each file one at a time?

Comment: Your best bet is to run multiple files in parallel as much as your hardware allows. You're running 87M sha256sum commands. If each takes 1ms, it will be more than 24 hours in total.

Comment: @karakfa doesn't it run in parallel already ?

Comment: @karakfa what does the `&` do at the end of the awk command line ?

Comment: @CorentinLimier, yes the tasks run in the background.  Most likely in parallel based on system task manager scheduling of the 174 tasks. However, if you further split files you can get more throughput depending on your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of invoking awk once per input file:

```
for f in *; do
    awk '{print}' "$f" > "${f}.${sfx}"
done
```

Try invoking awk just once total:

```
awk -v sfx="$sfx" 'FNR==1{close(out); out=FILENAME"."sfx} {print > out}' *
```

btw this:

```
    tmp="echo -n "$1" | sha256sum | cut -f1 -d\" \""
    tmp | getline cksum
    $1=cksum;
    print $0;
    close(tmp)
```

should be written as this for robustness:

```
    cmd = "printf \047" $1 "\047 | sha256sum"
    if ( (cmd | getline cksum) > 0 ) {
        split(cksum,arr)
        $1 = arr[1]
    }
    else {
        print "Failed to get checksum" | "cat>&2"
    }
    close(cmd)
    print
```

Comment: I doubt this will make a dent in the time. He's running 87M sha256sum commands. If each takes 1ms, it will be more than 24 hours

Comment: I think it's `lakhs`.  More confusing in numerals: 1,00,000.

Comment: I've no idea. I actually suspect the OP wants to call sha256sum once per file and the fact he's calling it once per line is probably a bug but idk about that either so I asked in a comment.

Comment: I think I recall from a previous question that they really need the checksum once per line. Using a language which can do this natively might help though if it's a lot of checksums it's still going to take time.

Comment: Regarding the spelling of the term, both variants are in relatively common use. I guess it might depend on which language you are coming from (Hindi vs Tamil or whatever).

Comment: my bad. 5 lacs means 500k. i want every files output in separated file only. not in single file.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced problems using `close` with `getline` takes a lot of time. If `close` is removed, then its very quick. But `getline` misfunctions in that case.